# Find most frequent words on a webpage (using Jsoup)?

Tags: java, jsoup, html, word-frequency

In my project I have to count the most frequent words in a Wikipedia article. I found Jsoup for parsing HTML format, but that still leaves the problem of word frequency. Is there a function in Jsoup that count the freqeuncy of words, or any way to find which words are the most frequent on a webpage, using Jsoup ?

Thanks.

Comment: No, Jsoup is not statistics/histogram tool. It is simple XML/HTML parser.

Comment: Are there an APi that i can use for my problem?

Comment: Maybe there are but I am not aware of any and questions about tools recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow so you shouldn't be asking here about them. But you can write your own code using for instance `Map<String, Integer>` where you would store each word and its count. After you are done with mapping find max count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you could use Jsoup to get the text from the webpage, like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
String text = doc.body().text();
```

Then, you need to count the words and find out which ones are the most frequent ones. [This code](https://gist.github.com/EmilHernvall/953748/)  looks promising. We need to modify it to use our String output from Jsoup, something like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.*;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class JsoupWordCount {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Map<String, Word> countMap = new HashMap<String, Word>();

        //connect to wikipedia and get the HTML
        System.out.println("Downloading page...");
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();

        //Get the actual text from the page, excluding the HTML
        String text = doc.body().text();

        System.out.println("Analyzing text...");
        //Create BufferedReader so the words can be counted
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] words = line.split("[^A-ZÃƒâ€¦Ãƒâ€žÃƒâ€“a-zÃƒÂ¥ÃƒÂ¤ÃƒÂ¶]+");
            for (String word : words) {
                if ("".equals(word)) {
                    continue;
                }

                Word wordObj = countMap.get(word);
                if (wordObj == null) {
                    wordObj = new Word();
                    wordObj.word = word;
                    wordObj.count = 0;
                    countMap.put(word, wordObj);
                }

                wordObj.count++;
            }
        }

        reader.close();

        SortedSet<Word> sortedWords = new TreeSet<Word>(countMap.values());
        int i = 0;
        int maxWordsToDisplay = 10;

        String[] wordsToIgnore = {"the", "and", "a"};

        for (Word word : sortedWords) {
            if (i >= maxWordsToDisplay) { //10 is the number of words you want to show frequency for
                break;
            }

            if (Arrays.asList(wordsToIgnore).contains(word.word)) {
                i++;
                maxWordsToDisplay++;
            } else {
                System.out.println(word.count + "\t" + word.word);
                i++;
            }

        }

        time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;

        System.out.println("Finished in " + time + " ms");
    }

    public static class Word implements Comparable<Word> {
        String word;
        int count;

        @Override
        public int hashCode() { return word.hashCode(); }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) { return word.equals(((Word)obj).word); }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Word b) { return b.count - count; }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Downloading page...
Analyzing text...
42  of
24  in
20  Wikipedia
19  to
16  is
11  that
10  The
9   was
8   articles
7   featured
Finished in 3300 ms
```

Some notes:

- This code can ignore some words, like "the", "and", "a" etc. You will have to customize it.
- It seems to have problems with unicode characters sometimes. Although I don't experience this, someone in the comments did.
- This could be done better and with less code.
- Not well tested.

Enjoy !

Comment: Why not just map words to their counts? A whole class that's basically a string decorator that doesn't abstract more functionality seems like a lot of overkill. Just curious.

Comment: I ran this same code but I am getting a different output. I am getting a count of 27 for â€“.

Comment: @LittlePanda, Strange, what URL are you using ?  And yes, this code is not perfect, as I threw it together in a few minutes.

Comment: @JonasCz - I copied and ran this code. I didnt change anything.

Comment: think you, that's exactly what i need, it missing now to remove stop words.

Comment: @Adem, What do you mean by this ?

Comment: @LittlePanda, Now that's something I don't understand ! Probably the problem is that something is not configured properly for UTF-8. Maybe old version of Jsoup ? Ah well.

Comment: @Adem, OK, I will post updated code to ignore these in a little while.

Comment: @JonasCz - I have Jsoup 1.8.1. I think the problem might be the characters the source code is getting split with - line.split("[^A-ZÃƒâ€¦Ãƒâ€žÃƒâ€“a-zÃƒÂ¥ÃƒÂ¤ÃƒÂ¶]+")??

Comment: @LittlePanda, But it works fine for me.. The regex is like that so that the program does not treat words with such a character in the middle as two separate words. But do play around with it, if you want !

Comment: @ JonasCz :this is not exactly what i want. the problem that i need to expand extrawords from the begnning.in this code, if I  want to get for example the 10 first most frequent words, i cant because i elemenate from them the extrawords. i'am getting only 2. I hope i have explained my problem

Comment: @Adem, It should still give you the next 10 most frequent words excluding the extra ones, at least it does for me.

Comment: that's the result of the ancien code: 
 761 Apple
725 the
401 and
370 of
326 Â
307 to
285 a
278 in
218 s
199 The
137 on
Finished in 1925 ms 
 and then the result of the modified code:
'Analyzing text...
761 Apple
370 of
326 Â
307 to
218 s
199 The
Finished in 1960 ms'

Comment: @Ah, I see it now ! One minuite and il'l post the fix.

Comment: @Adem, Fixed now ! Just changed the last loop a bit.

Comment: @JonasCz , that's ok, Thinks a lot :)

Comment: @DaveNewton, I somehow missed your comment, but _yes_, this could be done better. Since i'm lazy, I copied this from somewhere else, and adapted it. Also, with this approach, more functionality (eg. different properties for words) can be added later without too many changes.